# SKPhysicsBody contact with the SKSpriteNode

Tags: skphysicsbody

I try to make a contact between two nodes and the code is below:

```
SKTexture *bgTexttureRiverLeft = [SKTexture textureWithImageNamed:@"River_Left_Main"];
bgTexttureRiverLeft.filteringMode = SKTextureFilteringNearest;
SKSpriteNode *spriteRiverLeft = [SKSpriteNode spriteNodeWithTexture:bgTexttureRiverLeft];
spriteRiverLeft.texture.filteringMode = SKTextureFilteringNearest;
spriteRiverLeft.anchorPoint = CGPointZero;
spriteRiverLeft.position = CGPointZero;
spriteRiverLeft.zPosition = -10;
spriteRiverLeft.name = @"River_Left_Main";


spriteRiverLeft.size = CGSizeMake(spriteRiverLeft01.size.width *0.8, _screenSize.height);

spriteRiverLeft.physicsBody = [SKPhysicsBody bodyWithRectangleOfSize:CGSizeMake(spriteRiverLeft.size.width*1.85, spriteRiverLeft.size.height*2)];
spriteRiverLeft.physicsBody.categoryBitMask = river_left_Category;
spriteRiverLeft.physicsBody.collisionBitMask = kajakCategory; 
spriteRiverLeft.physicsBody.contactTestBitMask = kajakCategory ;
spriteRiverLeft.physicsBody.dynamic = YES;
spriteRiverLeft.physicsBody.allowsRotation = YES;

[self addChild:spriteRiverLeft];
```

Because SKTexture River_Left_Main is not a straight line (twisting river), the contact between kayak and the edge of river is perfect some place and not that perfect another places (too late or too early).

My question is how to make the contact more precise? Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

CGMutablePathRef path = CGPathCreateMutable();

is the answer. A lot of job but you have to do what you have to do!